How to avoid errors with singular Jacobians in solve_bvp?
I am trying to decelerate a rocket in space as it approaches Mars to enter its final orbit. I am trying to use solve_bvp to describe the position and the velocity of the rocket as it decelerates. The code is as follows.
When running this code, the solver fails to converge, with a message stating "A singular Jacobian encountered when solving the collocation system." How can I fix this? Thank you for helping.
import numpy as np 
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp, solve_bvp 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Define necessary constants 
Cd = .2 
A = 11.4  # m^2 
G = 6.673 * 10**-11 # Nm**2/kg**2 
m1 = 5.97219 * 10**24  # kg 
re = 6.371 * 10**6  # m 
Isp = 300  # sec 
Isp2 = 450 # sec 
g0 = 9.81  # m/s^2 
p0 = 101325  # Pa 
M = .0289652  # kg/mol 
R = 8.31446  # J/(mol*K) 
T0 = 288.15  # K 
L = .0065  # K/m 
dry_mass = 21000 # kg 
slv_mass = 2300 # kg 
payload_mass = 2180 # kg 
stage1_fuel_mass = 200000 # kg 
stage2_fuel_mass = 50000 # kg 
deceleration_fuel_mass = stage2_fuel_mass 
total_mass = dry_mass + stage1_fuel_mass + stage2_fuel_mass + payload_mass + slv_mass + deceleration_fuel_mass 
total_mass_2 = stage2_fuel_mass + payload_mass + slv_mass + deceleration_fuel_mass 
m2dot = 2100 # kg/s 
m2dot2 = 400 # kg/s

total_mass_3 = payload_mass + slv_mass + deceleration_fuel_mass

required_velocity = 3000
#ta,tb = sol2.t[-1],sol2.t[-1]+900 
ta,tb = 0,900
#va,vb = sol2.y[1][-1], required_velocity  
va,vb = 40000, required_velocity

def fun3(t,S): 
    h,v = S 
    dhdt = v 
    dvdt = (m2dot2*(-Isp2*g0+v))/((total_mass_3)-m2dot2*t) 
    return np.vstack([dhdt,dvdt])

def bc(Sa,Sb): 
    bc1 = Sa[1] - va 
    bc2 = Sb[1] - vb 
    return np.array([bc1,bc2])

t_bvp = np.linspace(ta,tb,1000) 
S = np.zeros((2,t_bvp.size)) 
sol3 = solve_bvp(fun3, bc, t_bvp, S, max_nodes = 10000)


print(sol3)

I've tried changing various boundary values given. For example, if I change the first boundary condition to be Sa[0] instead of Sa[1], making it refer to the first value of the state variable, just as an experiment. When doing this, the code does not have an issue with Jacobian point, and if I increase the maximum number of nodes, it actually solves. Of course, this is without the boundary values I want to use. I think this means there is something wrong with my boundaries, and I am not totally sure what it could be.
